# i don't quite understand the syntax where it adds the sum of 5 digits input

Tags: c, syntax

i have been reading the discussion codes and don't understand the syntax in which the sum of 5 digits is outputted. i thought C reads everything top down, left right so how is sum both % 10 and /10 syntactically?

this is a challenge from hackerrank, input 5 digits and output sum of 5 digits.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <math.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main() {

int n;
scanf("%d", &n);
int sum = 0;

while(n)
{
    sum += n % 10;
    n/= 10;
}

printf("%d\n", sum);
//Complete the code to calculate the sum of the five digits on n.
return 0;
}
```

sample input 10564
sampe output 16

Comment: `n % 10` isolates the least significant digit `4` which is added to `sum`. The number is then divided by 10, which removes that digit leaving `1056`. The two lines are executed in the sequence you wrote them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The sum is not "both `% 10` and `/10` syntactically".

`n % 10` is the least significant (rightmost) digit of `n`.
This is what gets added to `sum`.

Then `n /= 10` (`n = n / 10`) "chops off" that digit from `n`, and the process repeats.

You can work through it by hand:

Set `n = 12345` and `sum = 0`.

`12345` is not zero, so enter the loop:

`12345 % 10` is `5`, so `sum += 5`, which makes `5`.
`12345 / 10` is `1234` , so `n = 1234`.

Now, `n` is `1234`, which is not zero.

`1234 % 10` is `4`, so `sum += 4`, which makes `9`.
`1234 / 10` is `123`, so `n = 123`.

`123` is not zero...

And so on, until `n` becomes zero, which will happen after there is only one digit left.

Comment: thank you, i understand its method to add the sum now. i am not familiar with "while" loops.

Answer (score 0):

Altough the compiler can make some optimizations so your code might change, C does work on your code top down.

The thing that happends here in the while loop

`sum += n % 10;` == `sum = sum + n % 10;`
first of all, `%` operator is activate, and then the `+` operator.
So, first you get the last significant digit of the number, and then you sum it up to your result and assign it into `sum`.

the same thing happens in `n/= 10;`. first you divide the number that saved in `n` and then you store the result in `n`.

I hope it answers your question.

Answer (score 0):

How it works :

While n isn't null, you add the rest of the division n/10.
If n = 10564 :
At the first iteration, you get 4, the result of 10564%10.
Then, by dividing 10564 by 10 you get 1056,4. 
BUT n is an integer value, so you get n = 1056

By doing the same operation, you always get the units of n and add it to the sum.

Answer (score 0):

Well, the syntax and code seems correct. The syntax 'sum +=  n % 10' could also be written as 'sum = sum + n%10'. And 'n/=10' as 'n=n/10'. This will support that c reads everything from top to bottom and from left to right.

Answer (score 0):

the following description of what is happening in you code should help you to understand

```
#include <stdio.h>
// note, it is poor programming practice
//       to include header files those contents are not used
//#include <string.h>
//#include <math.h>
//#include <stdlib.h>

int main() 
{
    // assume input is 54321
    int n;
    scanf("%d", &n);
    int sum = 0;

    while(n)
    {
        // values at each loop
        sum += n % 10;     // remember n%10 means the remainder of n/10
            // n%10 =1 sum = 1 
            // n%10 =2 sum = 3
            // n%10 =3 sum = 6
            // n%10 =4 sum = 10
            // n%10 =5 sum = 15
        n/= 10;  // shorthand for: n = n/10
            //n = 5432
            //n = 543
            //n = 54
            //n = 5
            //n = 0
    }

    printf("%d\n", sum);
    //Complete the code to calculate the sum of the five digits on n.
    return 0;
}
```

the output is:

```
15
```